# Redrawing issues when moving a control

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I am trying to move some controls around on a WinForm with the mouse. I am using the code below. To see my issue start a new project in VS add the code below. Set the form BackGroundImage to any image then add any control. Set the control events for MouseUp, MouseDown, and MouseMove. Start debugging and click and move the control. The image in the form starts getting erased. I have tried several different suspend drawing classes and methods I have found on the net but nothing I have found lets me move the controls around without serious flickering or not being able to see the move. Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. If you set the same events to the up, move, and down events of the form, it moves fine with out any flickering.

```
private bool _mouseDown;
private Point _startPoint;
private void Event_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        _mouseDown = true;
        _startPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    }
}

private void Event_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    _mouseDown = false;
}

private void Event_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (_mouseDown)
    {
        Control s = sender as Control;
        s.Location = new Point(e.X + s.Left - _startPoint.X, e.Y + s.Top - _startPoint.Y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Set *DoubleBuffer* property to *true*

Comment: On form or control??

Comment: Where the control is moving. Your form.